# confusion about C++ name lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

According to my knowledge, the name in a nested scope will hide the same name in the enclosing scope, just like what shows below:

```
namespace ttt {
    class A {};

    void test(const A&, int)
    {
        cout << "ttt::test()" << endl;
    }
}

void test(const ttt::A&, int)
{
    cout << "global::test()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    void test(const ttt::A&, int);
    ttt::A a;
    test(a, 1);
}
```

the declaration of `void test(const ttt::A&, int);` in the main function hides the same name which is in the namespace `ttt`, so the console prints `global::test()`(Tested in Visual Studio 2019)

However, when I try the code below:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const string& str)
{
    os << "global::operator" << endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const string & str);
    string a = "STD's operator";

    cout << a << "STD's operator" << endl;
}
```

I try to overload the `<<` operator which is a template defined in STL with my own version of `<<`. According to the first example, the declaration of `operator<<` in main should hide the STL defined version of `<<`, then the desired output should be

```
global::operator
global::operator
global::operator
```

or a compile error, since I don't know whether `endl` can be converted to `string`.
however, the result of the program is:

```
global::operator
STD's operator
```

So the second and the last `<<` in the statement `cout << a << "STD's operator" << endl;` invokes the STL's `<<`, not the overloaded one define by me. Shouldn't the `<<` already be hidden by the declaration `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const string & str);` in main ?

Someone may say `"STD's operator"` is `const char*`, so that the Argument Dependent Lookup(ADL) adds a better candidate  which is `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const char*)` from `std` namespace. If this is true, then how to explain the first example. The ADL procedure in the first example may add `ttt::test(const A&, int)` into overloading candidate and that would cause ambiguity in the first example, but that didn't happen, the `ttt::test(const A&, int)` just been hidden.

Page 798 of "C++ primer 5th" says that "When we pass an object of a class type to a function, the compiler searches the namespace in which the argument’s class is defined *in addition to* the normal scope lookup". I think my confusion is about the accurate meaning of *in addition to*.
If it means that the class's namespace has the same precedence of the scope where the function is called, then the first example should cause ambiguity.
If it means that the class's namespace has lower precedence, then all the `<<` in the main function in the second example should be hidden by the version defined by me.
If it means that the class's namespace has higher precedence, then the first example should print `"ttt::test()"`.
So what happened?

Comment: `"STD's operator"` is not a `std::string`, it's a `const char[N]`.

Answer (score 2):

ADL is *not* performed if one of the candidate functions is declared at block scope, like your block scope function declarations. (When ADL is performed, it indeed has no special preferential treatment when picking the *most* viable candidate)

So your first example, `void test(const ttt::A&, int);` (which is a block scope declaration for `::test`), means that `ttt::test` is no longer a candidate, and the global `::test` is called (removing the block scope declaration makes it ambiguous)

---

I believe that you are correct here and the second example should call your global operator after constructing a `std::string`.

Compilers seem to agree that `std::cout << a << "STD's operator" << std::endl` compiles to the equivalent of `std::operator<<(::operator<<(std::cout, a), "STD's operator").operator<<(std::endl)`. The `<< std::endl` is fine since it's found by member lookup instead of ADL. The problem is that ADL is still used to find `std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`

Reading directly from the C++11 standard on what should happen:

"Operators in expressions" [over.match.oper]p2:

> If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements this operator [...]. In this case, overload resolution is used to determine which operator function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator. Therefore, the operator notation is first transformed to the equivalent function-call notation as summarized in Table 11 (where @ denotes one of the operators covered in the specified subclasses)

Both operands are of class types, so user-defined operator functions are considered as expected. The relevant subclause of table 11 is 13.5.2, with the expression `a@b`, which is `(a).operator@(b)` as a member function and `operator@(a, b)` as a non-member function.

[over.match.oper]p3

> [...] for a binary operator `@` with a left operand of type *cv1* `T1` and a right operand of type *cv2* `T2`, three sets of candidate functions, designated *member candidates*, *non-member candidates* and *built-in candidates*, are constructed as follows:
> [...]
> The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of `operator@` in the context of the expression according to the usual lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2) except that all member functions are ignored.

Where §3.4.2 is [basic.lookup.arg] "Argument-dependent name lookup".

[basic.lookup.arg]p3 says:

> Let *X* be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let *Y* be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If *X* contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - a block-scope declaration that is not a *using-declaration*, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then *Y* is empty. [...] The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union of *X* and *Y*.

Looking only at `std::cout << "STD's operator"` for simplicity, the name looked up is `operator<<`. The unqualified lookup finds the block scope declaration for `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const string & str);` only (and all other declarations are hidden). But since the function declaration in a block scope was found, ADL shouldn't happen and there are no further non-member candidates.

Thus the set of candidate functions is only the global `::operator<<(std::ostream & os, const string &)` and the member `operator<<` in `std::ostream` and its base classes, of which the global function is the most viable.

Compilers seem to ignore this rule when looking up operators, always performing ADL even if there is a block scope declaration. Writing `operator<<(std::cout, "STD's operator")` does it correctly and outputs `global::operator`.

Comment: *"When the postfix-expression in a function call ([expr.call]) is an unqualified-id"* Nothing in `cout << a << "STD's operator" << endl` is a postfix expression in a function call expression. Nor is there an actual function call expression.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The rewritten form as `operator<<(operator<<(cout, a), "STD's operator")` is

Comment: The C++20 text you quote is different to the wording [up to C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.oper#3.2). It doesn't mention [basic.lookup.unqual] explicitly. And the OP explicitly tagged this C++11. So this leads me to believe that unless this change was part of a defect report, and so applies retroactively, then a compiler vendor could be excused for not doing the regular unqualified name lookup, in pre-c++20 mode.

Skipping that, we are left with nothing that hides the result of ADL.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica There is similar wording in C++17 which doesn't use the ADL results if there is a block scope function declaration: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#3 which would apply in the "usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls" as quoted in C++17 (It seems that the standard intends for `(a) << (b)` to be completely equivalent to `operator<<(a, b)` if a non-member function is chosen, so the same lookup rules should apply). Though yes I didn't see the C++11 tag and will swap out the quotes

Comment: [basic.lookup.argdep]/3 is not just similar, it's the same between standards. And it doesn't contradict my point. It hinges on unqualified lookup *having been performed*. My point was that a vendor *could have* potentially understood that unqualified lookup is to be skipped. So `X` there would be empty. That's moot anyway. GCC and Clang both behave incorrectly with types that are not from `std` (https://wandbox.org/permlink/SRQRl5ne0YYTEsai), they see an ambiguity. The only remaining point of interest in the OP is `endl`. That overload should not be hidden, since its a member function.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Your example shows incorrect behaviour. `a << 1 << b;` is supposed to work exactly the same as `operator<<(operator<<(a, 1), b)` (both trying to call `ttt::A const& operator<<(const ttt::A&, int);` as the only candidate function), but it doesn't. And unqualified lookup is done as evidenced by [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OSwRIXbLJuXmiFRJ)

Answer (score 0):

Only in addition to @Artyer's answer.

In practice, you shouldn't ever provide a different definition of `std::` functions in a different namespace because the call may accidentally go into a `std::` version, with no warning or error.

The robust solution is to name your functions differently or wrap you arguments in a different class object, so that you never accidentally call a `std::` function when you don't intend to.

For example, if you want a version of `std::isnan` that works correctly with `-ffast-math`, call it `isnan2`, not `isnan` which might resolve into `std::isnan`.

A part of being a good software engineer is *preventing* potential problems for yourself in the future. And avoiding name clashes with `std::` functions which may be found via ADL is *robust engineering* - a philosophy or way of thinking about engineering that makes accidental semantic changes of existing correctly working code impossible.

In your example, there is no need or justification for creating another version of `std::operator<<` in another namespace. But there are undesirable problems which arise from from such a decision. In other words, the reward is 0, but the risk is infinite.